# "I would be very glad to have a brief account of same." Not sure if it is "of same" or "of some"

Tags: expressions

I met this sentence:

> Should there be any more experiments I would be very glad to have a brief account **of same**.

It appears in [this context](https://www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.03199/?sp=22).

The question is, does it make sense to say "of same" (an account of the same kind as before) or this is just a mistake made by the typist and the author of the text had in mind the construction "of some" experiments.

Comment: Hi, Robert. There are lots of answers on our sister site [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235076/can-you-use-same-without-the), [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195122/is-it-grammatical-to-use-same-or-the-same-in-substitution-for-an-objective-p), [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31700/some-same-thing-person) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30000/using-the-expression-the-same-for-a-previously-mentioned-item).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use of **same**, or (as Teacher KSHuang indicates) **the same**, is rather old-fashioned - your example dates from 1904. It refers back to the **any more experiments**, asking for accounts of them. And using **them** rather than **same** would be a more common form these days

> Should there be any more experiments I would be very glad to have a brief account of **them**.